# Using Pagedown I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'attachEvent' of null"

Tags: javascript, pagedown

When ever I load a page with a very simple example I get

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'attachEvent' of null. Markdown.Editor.js:273

in my Chrome console log.

In Firebug I get

```
elem is null [Break On This Error]  
if (elem.attachEvent) {
Markdo...itor.js (line 273)
```

Why am I getting those errors and how do I solve it?

Comment: `null.attachEvent` <-- it's the same as this. Why doesn't *that* work, and why *is* `elem` evaluating to `null` here?

Comment: That `elem` evaluates to `null` and you should find out why.

Comment: @pst I did find out why, the element doesn't exist yet if you run the javascript-wmd-initializing code in the HEAD. This is a self-answer question because Google shows a lot of people encountering the problem, and the [only demo](http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/source/browse/#hg%2Fdemo%2Fbrowser) shows the code being executed at the end of the body -- not where people are likely to place it when they try to incorporate the library.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at the code in the [demo](http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/source/browse/demo/browser/demo.html).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function () {
    var converter1 = Markdown.getSanitizingConverter();
    var editor1 = new Markdown.Editor(converter1);
    editor1.run();
  } );
</script>
```

See where it is located? At the end of the body. This means the elements *already* exist. However, you're probably loading this JavaScript in the head. Instead, put the code in a [.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) block, or put it back at the end of the body (or after the textarea in the DOM).